# MongoDB Query to move field from root document to sub-document based on condition

Tags: mongodb

Data Migration. I need to move "ActionType" field from root document to sub-document based on condition.

Condition: Sub-documents which are not null and has at least one array of document.

I need to change from below structure

```
{
    "ItemId" : "ITM-A",
    "ActionType" : "Rent"
    "BucketInfo" : [ 
        {
            "BucketType" : "damage",
            "BucketDetailInfo" : []
        },
        {
            "BucketType" : "repair",
            "BucketDetailInfo" : [ 
                {                    
                    "EntityType" : "service"
                },
                {                    
                    "EntityType" : "service"                    
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "BucketType" : "missing",
            "BucketDetailInfo" : []
        }, 
        {
            "BucketType" : "broken",
            "BucketDetailInfo" : [ 
                {                    
                    "EntityType" : "service"                
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

to below structure, Action Type to be moved to sub-document which has array of document

```
{
    "ItemId" : "ITM-A", 
    "BucketInfo" : [ 
        {
            "BucketType" : "damage",
            "BucketDetailInfo" : []
        }, 
        {
            "BucketType" : "repair",
            "BucketDetailInfo" : [ 
                {                    
                    "EntityType" : "service",
                    "ActionType" : "Rent"                   
                },
                {                    
                    "EntityType" : "service",                  
                    "ActionType" : "Rent"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "BucketType" : "missing",
            "BucketDetailInfo" : []
        }, 
        {
            "BucketType" : "broken",
            "BucketDetailInfo" : [ 
                {                    
                    "EntityType" : "service",
                    "ActionType" : "Rent"                   
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Please, let me the how to achieve this.

Answer (score -1):

I achieved the result by below query

```
db.getCollection('Table').find( {},  {'ActionType' : 1}).forEach(function(doc){
    db.getCollection('Table').update(
    {_id: doc._id},
    { $set: { "BucketInfo.$[].BucketDetailInfo.$[].ActionType" : doc.ActionType } },
   { multi: true}
 )
});

db.getCollection('Table').update({}, {$unset: {ActionType:1}} , {multi: true});
```